# Multiple HTTPS domains on single IP?

Tags: https

Is it possible to create a webserver that will serve multiple HTTPS domains on a single public IP address? I know HTTP will support this, but what about SSL/TLS?

I am not interested in wildcard certificates such as `*.example.com`, because I also need to serve websites for `*.example.net`.

Comment: You can with SNI. Check [this post](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) and [this one](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/configure-apache-to-support-multiple-ssl-sites-on-a-single-ip-address/987). Those links are for apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through SNI and SAN/UC. SNI takes some set up work whereas SAN is an ordinary SSL certificate but with the [subject alternative name](http://www.ssl.com/subject_alternative_name) field utilized. Because of this I would recommend the SAN certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. For instance, [from GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.com/ssl/unified-communications/):

> Multi-domain SSL Certificates from GlobalSign utilize Subject
>   Alternative Names (SANs) to give you the flexibility to secure up to
>   100 different domain names, subdomains, and public IP addresses using
>   only one SSL Certificate and using only one IP address.